# Querying a limited ActiveRecord::Relation by chaining scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to query *just* the records in an ActiveRecord::Relation, without converting it to an array?

Chaining scopes on a `limit`ed relation can produce strange results:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, ->(number) { order('created_at DESC').limit(number) }
  scope :won_by, ->(player) { where(won_by: player) }
end

recent_games = Game.recent(10)

recent_games.won_by(player_one).size # 10
recent_games.won_by(player_two).size # 10
```

What's the nicest way to prevent `limit` from affecting subsequent queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first(N)` instead of `limit` #my bad

**Update**
Sorry about the answer, thought I remember myself chaining scopes using `first`, anyway, **limit** is indeed a bit of a roller coaster ride. The rule is that the **limit** method should always be chained last! I think it's best to use an instance method when using the scope, `recent` here.

Comment: `first(N)` returns an array, so calling `won_by` will raise an exception

Answer (score 0):

Current solution is to restrict the query using `where` (and get rid of the unnecessary limit with `unscope`):

```
recent_games = Game.recent(10)
recent_games = recent_games.where(id: recent_games).unscope(:limit)
```

But I wonder if there is a nicer solution?